# Convertir Data Table a INT y Sumar Valores

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen Dia,

Necesito ayuda en lo siguiente, Tengo una table que se llena mediante un DataTable, ahora inclui a mi proyecto un dropdownlist(DDL) para cambiar una columna en especifica dependiendo de la fecha seleccionado en el DDL, Mi inconveniente es con la parte de reemplazar los valores de la columna con la nueva teniendo en cuenta que el resultado puede ser mas de un registro por ello quisiera hacer una suma y el resultado colocarlo en un INT y hacer el reemplazo en la columna, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
      if (ddlMontoPorMes.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    foreach (DataColumn MONTOREC in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            object fielsd = dtRow["NROACCRUAL"];
                            //Hago la busqueda de los nuevos valores por aqui 
                            DataTable dt1 = Helper_wsWillisBudget.SumaRecibosPorMes(fielsd.ToString(), ddlMontoPorMes.SelectedValue);
                            //Aqui quiero sumar todos los valores para tener un solo resultado y asignarlo a la columna
                            int suma = int.Parse(dt1);
                            row.SetField("MONTOREC", dt1);
                        }


                    }
                }

            }
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tienes +3, viendo tu pregunta y su título no convence para esa puntuación. A ver si entendí, a partir de una nueva consulta con el método **SumaRecibosPorMes** quieres sumar los registros del nuevo `DataTable` y agregarlo a todo los registros de un `DataTable` existente (viendo tu código hace eso). Podrías decirme que columnas quieres sumar del `DataTable` que trae tu método **SumaRecibosPorMes** o solo es una columna.

Comment: @Davlio Exactamente, solo que me falto la parte de la suma. el DataTable trae registros numeros dependiendo del criterio de busqueda pueden ser de 0 a 10 registros a sumas

Answer (score 2):

Para sumar las filas de un `DataTable` aprovecharías en usar LINQ, usando la extensión [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) para un `DataTable` y [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) para un `DataRow`.

```
if (ddlMontoPorMes.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
        {           
            DataTable dt1 = Helper_wsWillisBudget.SumaRecibosPorMes(dtRow["NROACCRUAL"].ToString(), ddlMontoPorMes.SelectedValue);
            int suma = dt1.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>(0));
            row["MONTOREC"] = suma;
        }
    }
}
```

*Como te indico en el comentario, la respuesta solo considera la primera columna al usar `x.Field<int>(0)`. En caso tengas una columna definida sería `x.Field<int>("MiColumna")`.*

---

Otra de las opciones que podrías usar para realizar la suma de una columna es [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
decimal monto = 0.0M;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Monto", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add(1);
dt.Rows.Add(2);
dt.Rows.Add(3);                        

monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Compute("Sum(Monto)", ""));

Console.WriteLine(monto);
```

[**Ejemplo**](http://rextester.com/UGJQRD66093)

Comment: Yo nunca he trabajado con LINQ, voy a intentar con esta forma a ver si funciona, lo logre hacer de esta forma "object sumar = rowItem["TComis"];
"suma += Convert.ToInt32(sumar);" Voy a revisarlo con tu metodo y lo marco como respuesta si tambien funciona,

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta de igual manera

Comment: @Hans modifiqué mi respuesta para que puedas usar también `DataTable.Compute` (con su ejemplo) y no tengas que estar recorriendo cada fila de tu `DataTable.